# Applying the dominated convergence theorem to $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n$, for $x \in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

> $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^n$, for $x \in [0,1]$.

I'm using the dominated convergence theorem on a few problems and keep running into this issue.  What's the limit of the above function?  Clearly, for $x$ between $0$ and $1$, the limit is $0$, but what about at the endpoints, $0$ and $1$?  Or do we not care about the endpoints in the integration, when taking a limit inside of the integral sign?

(The integration bounds in the problem are $0$ and $1$.)

Comment: end points have measure $0$.

Comment: The limit function is $0$ everywhere except at $1$, where the function is $1$, and hence the integral is $0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much, @voldemort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 1^n= 1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}0^n=0$.

Since $1^n=1$ for every value of $n$, the first limit is just a limit of a sequence in which every term is $1$.

However $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ is not altered by changing $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, so the values at the endpoints don't affect the value of the integral.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelHardy.  Can I ask a follow-up question that's pretty similar to this one?  What about the limit, as x -> infinity, of the series of 1/n^(x)?  Again, using the dominated convergence theorem, I take the limit inside of the summation.  Now for every n > 1, every term in this series is just zero.  But, the series starts at n=1.  In the problem, the series' index says n>/= 1.  So at n=1, I have a 1^(infinity) situation.  So, is the limit of this series ...1 ...or 0?  Is there a contribution of 1, from n=1?  Thanks...

Comment: ...and there is no measure zero argument to be made for series

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac 1 {n^x}$ $=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac 1 {n^x}\right)$.  That is equal to $1+\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac 1 {n^x}$, provided that latter limit exists. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $1^\infty$ is problematic if you're talking about $\lim f^g$ where $\lim f=1$ and $\lim g=\infty$.  In that case, the limit can be a number between $1$ and $\infty$.  But $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} 1^x$ is a limit of the function that is constantly equal to $1$, since $1^x=1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ah, right.  I agree with your answer.  Prior to evaluating this limit, I had showed that the series converges uniformly in the set [1+$\delta$, $\infty$), but I don't see how this should change the evaluation of the limit that I am asking about...(so i'm pretty sure the solutions that I looked at  are incorrect).  Thanks again, @MichaelHardy.